# creation a table from a default module

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation

I have used of bisection method for finding the root of a function:

```
bisect[f_, {x1_, x2_, \[Epsilon]_}] :=
 Module[
  {low = Min[x1, x2], high = Max[x1, x2], mid = N[(x1 + x2)/2], 
   fmid = N[f[(x1 + x2)/2]]},
   While[Abs[fmid] > \[Epsilon],
   If[fmid < 0, low = mid, high = mid];
   mid = N[(low + high)/2];
   fmid = N[f[mid]]];
    mid]
```

If we have `f[x_]:=x^2-10` we will face to

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 10
bisect[f, {0, 4, 0.0001}]
N[%]
3.16229
```

But finally I want to create a table with functions and their roots in a such a way that the variable of the table be `y`. Of course with the guarantee in which x1 and x2 are chosen to satisfying the bisection condition for boundary condition for each function.

```
Table[bisect[x^(2y) - 10 y, {0, 50, 0.01}], {y, 1, 5}]
```

The first function in table with `y=1` will be similar as above, I mean `x^2-10`, and other functions in the same way. But it doesn't work correctly. Also, if `f` in the bisect variables in the first lines defined with two variables `x,y`, but it doesn't work again.

Comment: First of all, you are not returning anything from the `Module`. Add `;mid` before the last `]`. Secondly, `x^(2 y) - 10 y` is an expression, and Mathematica does not interpret this as a function. Replace this expression with `#^(2 y) - 10 y&`. With these two replacements everything should work.

Comment: Yes, it works very well.  Thanks a bunch.